# Calling an internal method from another Class - Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I'm still new to Nodejs and I want to send messages via WebSockets, so in my support socket class I have this :
**support.js**

```
class SupportSocket {
    /**
     * @constructor SupportSocket
     */
    constructor () {

    }

    SupportSocket = (IO_SERVER, IO_CLIENT) => {
        const USERS = [];

        // EntryPoints

        IO_CLIENT.on('joinTicketRoom', (data) => {
            Logger.info('%j', data);
            IO_CLIENT.join(data.tuid);
            USERS.push(data.uuid);
        });

        // THIS IS THE METHOD I WANT TO CALL IN OTHER CLASS
        const sendModifiedTicket = (data) => {
            IO_SERVER.in(data[0]._id).emit('OneTicketReload', data);
            Logger.info('%s%s', 'Ticket sent to room ', data[0]._id);
        };

    };
}
export default {
    'SupportSocket' : SupportSocket,
}
```

and in the other class I'm trying to call the internal method sendModifiedTicket like this : **Ticket.js**

```
import SupportSocket                     from 'app/routes/socket/support';
class SupportTicketRouter  {
    /**
     * @constructor StateRouter
     */
    constructor () {}
.
.
.
.
    sendTicketsSocket = (req, res, next) => {
        const TICKETS        = req.api.support.tickets;
        SupportSocket.sendModifiedTicket(TICKETS);
        next();
    };
```

so apparently i'm doing something wrong because I get this following error : 
**app_routes_socket_support__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.default.sendModifiedTicket is not a function**
can anyone help please ?
thank you !

Comment: If there is no extend and constructor is empty - you can ommit it entirely. When it comes to JS Docs you can use @class. And about what is wrong - try simply export default SupportSocket instead of wrapping it in object. And again if key in object has same name as value, you can ommit key name.

Comment: tried export default SupportSocket but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice - you're using scoped variable as static function - but it's not visible from where you're trying to use it. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: I didn't get it, what is the solution then? I tried replacing const sendModifiedTicket = ... with this.sendMoifiedTicket = ... but still same error

Comment: There is a lot to change, but basically you should learn how to use class methods or even consider if you want to use class or function approach. (ES6 classes are slower https://jsperf.com/es6-class-vs-es5-proto but this part is less important)

Comment: can you explain more please?